# clojure factorial solution using range and apply fp-oo exercise

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am working through Functional Programming for the Object-Oriented Programmer by Brian Marick and am stuck on exercise 4. The solution I came up with is the same as that at the companion github site: https://github.com/marick/fp-oo/blob/master/solutions/just-enough-clojure.clj.

Here is my version.

```
(def factorial (fn [num] (apply * (range 1 (inc num)))))
```

The result of executing that in the repl is:

```
user=> factorial 5
#object[user$factorial 0x3cd52491 "user$factorial@3cd52491"]
5
```

I expected 120. I created an intermediate function:

```
(def range-to (fn [num] (range 1 (inc num))))
```

Which I then use in the following:

```
user=> (range-to 5)
(1 2 3 4 5)
user=> (apply * (range-to 5))
120
```

The results I am getting are totally unexpected and not understood. What am I doing wrong and what are my results actually saying?

Comment: You call the `factorial` function with `(factorial 5)`. `factorial 5` will just evaluate `factorial` and `5` separately which is what you're seeing.

Comment: Your function is correct, by the way.

Comment: @Lee Well, that is what it seems to be doing, and what I understood. But, I still don't get it. If you look at how I used `apply *` to my range-to function, isn't that exactly as I am doing, via substitution, with my factorial function?

Comment: @Thumbnail how is my function correct if it doesn't give the result I expect? I presume you are stating it is correctly formatted and evaluated?

Comment: Your `factorial` function will work as you expect if you actually invoke it correctly from the REPL by typing `(factorial 5)` instead of `factorial 5`.

Comment: @Lee Too new to Clojure, I guess. Couldn't see it.

Comment: @BillTurner all lisps that I know of work that way.